# How to fix pgf boxplot error with only zero value in samples?

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

Following [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227773/what-is-wrong-with-this-pgfplots-boxplot) I am still figuring out how to properly handle different "borderline" cases with the `boxplot` feature provided by `pgfplots`. The following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \begin{axis}[boxplot/draw direction=y, ymode=log]
        \addplot+[boxplot] table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
          000.00\\
        };
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

leads to the following compilation error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.69         };
```

The number of zero samples doesn't change anything in the problem. Nevertheless, I was able to fix the issue by removing the "log" property of the y axis. Why does `boxplot` generate an error in such a case ?

Comment: Because the log of zero is undefined? But perhaps that shouldn't matter for a box plot in the x direction...

Comment: @darthbith I know that log is defined only R+* but I am not here computing log(0) but using a log scale whit data to be plotted as 0. I don't have such error when replacing the box plot by a simple plot (and of course no curve is displayed)

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of why this happens, vor do you want a workaround for getting this to compile?

Comment: @Jake Both, why this happens for my knowledge, and a workaround to have my generated plots always compiling